# Регулярные выражения Ruby

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня имеется строка, которая содержит нужную мне ссылку:

```
'<p><img src=\"blob:http://localhost:3000/ab0670a6-eba9-433c-b663-f69379c526ed\" style=\"width: 300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\"></p>'
```

Отсюда нужно взять:

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/ab0670a6-eba9-433c-b663-f69379c526ed
```

Т.е. можно взять строку, находящуюся между первыми обратными слешами.
Но как это сделать, никак не могу понять.

Пока додумался только до вот такого костыля:

```
my_link = string.split("\"")[1].split("\\").to_s.split("\"")[1]
```

Посмотреть костыль: https://repl.it/repls/SlightRustyLines

Comment: Ruby я не знаю, но эта регулярка "string.match(/"([^"]*)\"/g)[0]" работает. Код на js - находит массив всех элементов между кавычками и выводит 1

Answer (score 0):

Сплитить не по одному символу, а по подстроке из двух:

```
string.split('\"')[1]
```

или "взять все между кавычкой и слешом":

```
string[/(?<=")[^\\]+/]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = /you_regex/.match(you_string)
  if $~!=nil
       first=$1.to_s
       second=$2.to_s
  end
```

искомое попадает в служебную переменную `$~`, я из нее брал нужное (см. туториал ruby regex), напр. `$1` из первого выражения в скобках

Comment: Ну и где сама регулярка?